# Access to factory from protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Hi I have small factory (*myFactory*) in my application:

```
.factory('myFactory', ['$q',  function ($q) {

      function myMethod() {
        .....
      }

      return {
        myMethod: myMethod
      };
}]);
```

I want to get access to *myFactory.myMethod()* in protractor test so in onPrepare() I'm using

```
browser.executeScript(function() {
    return angular.element(document).injector().get('myFactory'); 
}).then(function (myFactory) {
    console.log('myFactory: ', myFactory);
    myFactory.myMethod();
});
```

for *console.log('myFactory: ', myFactory)* I see I get object:

```
myFactory:  { 
    myMethod: {}
}
```

Then for *myFactory.myMethod();* I see error:
TypeError: object is not a function

Anyone know how I can get access to factory from protractor to be able to execute method?

Comment: This seems like an odd use-case. Protractor is meant for end-to-end tests, although it sounds like you are trying to use it for unit testing.There are better ways to test factories in unit tests.

Comment: There is some logic to retrieve login token in myMethod then I'm using that token in E2E tests for calls to API for verification. Thats why I need access to that factory from protractor. I can always replicate that logic in protractor to get token but i have it already in factory so I want to reuse it.

Comment: I can provide a somewhat generic answer based on angular services that I access in my own application via Protractor, but before I write that up...  What if you move the call to `myMethod()` into the `executeScript`?  i.e. `return angular.element(document).injector().get('myFactory').myMethod();`

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I use services to access user information in my app via Protractor, I went ahead and played around with this as close to your code as I could, my comment above should be your solution.  Here's the longer explanation:

So we have a service `Users`, with a function called `getCurrent()` that will retrieve the information of the current user.  So first time I tried code similar to yours:

```
browser.executeScript(function () {
    return angular.element(document.body).injector().get('Users');
}).then(function (service) {
    console.log(service); // logs object which has getCurrent() inside
    service.getCurrent(); // error, getCurrent() is not a function
});
```

This logged the `Users` object, and included the function `getCurrent()`, but I encountered the same error as you when I tried to chain the call `service.getCurrent()`.

What DID work for me, was simply moving the `.getCurrent()` into the execute script.  i.e.

```
browser.executeScript(function () {
    return angular.element(document.body).injector().get('Users').getCurrent();
}).then(function (service) {
    console.log(service); // logs John Doe, john.doe@email.com etc.
});
```

So applying that to your case, the below code should work:

```
browser.executeScript(function() {
    return angular.element(document).injector().get('myFactory').myMethod(); 
}).then(function (myFactory) {
    console.log(myFactory); // this should be your token
});
```

And just a minor FYI, for what it's worth you also could have written this code by passing in a string to `executeScript`:

```
browser.executeScript('return angular.element(document).injector().get("myFactory").myMethod()').then(function (val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```