# Can't use the result of angular injection in protractor. Error: ... is not a function

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am running some protractor tests for our angular app. For one of my Steps, I want to use an angular service to test a few things. The service looks like this:

```
'use strict';
define(['services/applicationServices'], function (module) {
    module.factory('myService',  ['otherService', function(otherService){

    function checkArray(array){
        //do stuff with array
        return result;
    }

    function getArray(id){
        //do stuff
        return result;
    }

    return {  
        checkArrayOfId: function(id){
            return checkArray(getArray(id));
        }
    };
 }]);
});
```

And the angular injection to retrieve the service in my e2e tests looks like this (service-helpers.js):

```
module.exports = {
        getService: function () {
            return browser.executeAsyncScript(function (callback) {
                var service = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('myService');
                return callback(service);
            })
        }
   };
```

But when I try to use the methods of the returned service objects, I get an error in node: service.checkArrayOfId is not a function:

```
    var serviceHelpers = require('../common/service-helpers.js');
    var util = require('util');

    serviceHelpers.getService().then(function(service){
            console.log(util.inspect(service, false, null)); 
            //logs this in node: { checkArrayOfId: {} }
            service.checkArrayOfId(109); 
            //error: service.checkArrayOfId is not a function.
    },
        function(error){
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

So, why isn't service.checkArrayOfId a function? What am I missing as to why the object returned has object properties that are empty e.g.: `{}` instead of being functions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `serviceHelpers` look like? It seems like an odd thing to return a service from anything other than just simple injection.

Comment: serviceHelpers is that small module where the browser.executeAsyncScript is run... the second code snippet here...

Comment: See if my answer [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093096/access-to-factory-from-protractor/40095581#40095581) points you in the right direction.

Comment: @Gunderson that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks much!

Comment: @TJGrist Awesome, no problem!